# UWP - Network access is denied

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I am developing an app that reads different file types from the network.
The file types that im reading are:

- PDF
- XML
  and more...

I am able to read all the fils type, **except XML**.
when I try to read it, I get the "Network access is denied"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you for sure set the `Internet` and/or `Private Networks` capabilities in your manifest?

Comment: I think you  could reference this [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e822c960-f15d-4789-9ff2-040212d0a67c/uwpaccess-a-file-on-a-network-drive?forum=wpdevelop). Then you need to have the right to access specific files. For this you need a fileTypeAssoziation.

Comment: @RareNCool - yes I did.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT - I already have it there...

Comment: @ranifisch Could you provide your Package.appxmanifest file or other codes to connect to the internet? I had asked a problem on this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107831/uwp-nas-network-access-denied) , and in my situation, I can't even download any files.